# Are memory modules mapped into process' virtual space?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory-management

I see that on Windows the function [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a number of modules loaded for a specified process (some of these should be system dlls like guard32.dll, version.dll, etc..)

My question is: are these modules mapped into the process' virtual space? Can I jump to an instruction located into one of these modules (of course knowing the address) from the main app code?

Comment: Why not give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: I usually study theory before messing around with practice, besides I'd like to know more about these modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the DLL's should be mapped into the process virtual address space. The mapping may not be backed by a real physical page if the code in that page has not been executed, and of course executing "random" bits of code without the right initialization or setup for the code to execute properly (e.g calling the processing function that uses some data that needs to be allocated in another function) will clearly end badly in some defintion of bad. Also bear in mind that the DLL may well be loaded at different addresses at different times you run the same code, etc, so you can't rely on the address of the DLL being constant - and it may well be completely different in another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just call `GetProcAddress` using the module which you got from `EnumProcessModules`. `GetProcAddress` calculates the function offset within the module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any DLL code that can be invoked directly from your own executable must be mapped into your process space.  You can get a precise chart of your process virtual memory space using SysInternal's VMMap utility: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533

As mentioned in other answers, the virtual address space is largely, if not entirely, dynamic.

There are cases where certain shared libraries are not directly accessible from your process.  These are typically sandboxed (secured) kernel or driver libraries, which are invoked through a special secure layer/API that performs parameter validation and then executes a ring/context switch into a different virtual process address space, or passes the command on via a secured inter-thread communication queue.  These are expensive operations so they are typically reserved for use only when there are benefits to system stability.